# Count the number of vowels in each word of a string

Tags: code-golf, string, number

This is a rather easy challenge.

## Challenge

Input will contain a string (not `null` or empty) of maximum length 100. Output the number of vowels in each word of the string, separated by spaces.

## Rules

- The string will not be more than 100 characters in length.
- The string will only contain alphabets `A-Z` , `a-z` and can also contain spaces.
- Input must be consumed from the `stdin` or command line arguments.
- Output must be outputted in the `stdout`.
- You can write a full program, or a function that takes input from the `stdin` and outputs the result.
- The vowels that your program/function needs to count are `aeiou` and `AEIOU`.

## Test Cases

```
This is the first test case     --> 1 1 1 1 1 2
one plus two equals three       --> 2 1 1 3 2
aeiou AEIOU                     --> 5 5
psst                            --> 0
the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog --> 1 2 1 1 2 2 1 1 1
```

## Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest submission (in bytes) wins.

Comment: Is there a reason why you insist on a rather restrictive I/O format? Not every language can (conveniently) interact with STDIN and STDOUT. [We have defaults for this](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2447/8478) (which you are of course free to override if you wish), which also allow command-line argument, function argument, return value etc. (They can also be found [in the tag wiki](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/code-golf/info).)

Comment: @MartinBüttner , "*Is there a reason why you insist on a rather restrictive I/O format?*" -- No. I just like `stdin` with `stdout`. I don't like to "get input" via the function arguments. command-line arguments seems ok. I've added it into the post.

Comment: WIKIPEDIA: `The name "vowel" is often used for the symbols that represent vowel sounds in a language's writing system, particularly if the language uses an alphabet. In writing systems based on the Latin alphabet, the letters A, E, I, O, U, and sometimes Y are all used to represent vowels. However, not all of these letters represent vowels in all languages.` What do YOU mean by vowels?

Comment: Is a single trailing space okay?

Comment: Use the Sandbox for Proposed Challenges.

Comment: is Y a vowel ? because in french it is so you might want to specifie what a vowel is :)

Comment: @WizLiz: "y" acts as a vowel occasionally in English as well. For example, in the word "why," the y is a vowel. To my knowledge, there are no English words without a vowel, but there are plenty of English words with no a, e, i, o, or u.

Comment: @edc65 , Edited the post to clarify it. Vowels are `a,e,i,o,u` and `A,E,I,O,U`.

Comment: @WizLiz , See above comment.

Comment: @AlexA. , Sure. [This answer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/50570/38214) also outputs a single trailing space.

Comment: @mbomb007 , Affirmative.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Pyth, 17 bytes

```
jdml@"aeiou"dcrzZ
```

Straightforward solution. Try it online: [Demonstration](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=jdml%40%22aeiou%22dcrzZ&input=This+is+the+first+test+case&debug=0) or [Test harness](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=zFz.zp%22%20--%3E%20%22%3C%2Bz*31d31%0Ajdml%40%22aeiou%22dcrzZ&input=Test%20Cases%3A%0AThis%20is%20the%20first%20test%20case%0Aone%20plus%20two%20equals%20three%0Aaeiou%20AEIOU%0Apsst&debug=0)

#### Explanation:

```
               z   input
              r Z  convert to lower-case
             c     split at spaces
  m                map each word d to:
    @"aeiou"d         filter d for chars in "aeiou"
   l                  length
jd                 join by spaces and implicitly print
```

Comment: It always amuses me when people write a Pyth solution and call it "Straightforward" (Though this one is admittedly easier to grasp than most) +1

Answer (score 11):

## C, <s>113 108 103</s> 96 bytes

Thanks [@andrea-biondo](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/40702/andrea-biondo) for a particularly nice 5 byte saving.

```
main(a,v,c)char**v;{do{for(a=0;c=*v[1]++%32;2016%(c+27)||a++);printf("%d ",a);}while(v[1][-1]);}
```

This still feels sort of bloated so hopefully I can get it down quite some bytes later tonight.

The interesting part is perhaps that

```
!(124701951%((c-65&31)+33))
```

will be `1` if `c` is an (upper or lower case) ASCII vowel, and `0` for other characters `a-zA-Z`. The subexpression `c-65&31` maps `'a'` and `'A'` to `0`, `'b'` and `'B'` to `2`, etc. When we add `33` the vowels correspond to the numbers `33, 37, 41, 47, 53` respectively, all of which are (conveniently) prime. In our range only such numbers will divide `124701951 = 33*37*41*47*53`, ie only for vowels will the remainder of `124701951%(...)` be zero.

EDIT: In this way one can consider the expression `!(n%((c-65&31)+s))` where `(n,s) = (124701951, 33)` as determining whether the character `c` is a vowel. In the comments [@andrea-biondo](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/40702/andrea-biondo) pointed out that the pair `(n,s) = (2016,28)` can also be used in this expression to determine vowelhood. I'll leave the current explanation in terms of primes above, but the reason this shorter pairing works is again because in the range 28--53 the only numbers with prime factors entirely in the set of prime factors of 2016 are 28, 32, 36, 42, 48, which correspond precisely to the vowels.

EDIT2: Another 5 bytes saved since `(c-65&31)+28` can be shortened to `c%32+27`.

EDIT3: Converted to a do-while loop to finally get it below 100 bytes.

Test cases:

```
$ ./vowelc "This is the first test case"
1 1 1 1 1 2 
$ ./vowelc "one plus two equals three"
2 1 1 3 2 
$ ./vowelc "aeiou AEIOU"
5 5 
$ ./vowelc "psst"                     
0
```

Comment: OMG! This is just awesome! You can save more bytes by using `a;` outside `main`. This way, you reduce some bytes as you don't need to declare `a` in `main(...)` and also, don't need to initialize `a` from the loop.

Comment: @CoolGuy: `a` is re-initialized at every loop, so you can't initialize it once to zero by declaring global. I wrote a small bruteforcer to find the smallest `(n, s)` pair such that `n%((c-65&31)+s)` is zero for vowels and non-zero for consonants (a-z, A-Z). I found `(2016, 28)` and it seems to work well: `!(2016%((c-65&31)+28))` is 5 chars shorter. Anyway, very nice solution :)

Answer (score 7):

## CJam, <s>21</s> 19 bytes

```
r{el_"aeiou"--,Sr}h
```

**How it works**:

```
r{               }h    e# Read the first word and enter a do-while loop
  el_                  e# Convert the word into lower case and take a copy of it
     "aeiou"           e# All small caps vowels
            -          e# Remove all vowels from the copied word
             -         e# Remove all non-vowels from the original word
              ,        e# At this point, we have a string with all vowels of the word
                       e# Simply take its length
               S       e# Put a space after the number of vowel
                r      e# Read the next word. This serves as the truthy condition for the
                       e# do-while loop for us as if there are no word left, this returns
                       e# null/falsy and the do-while loop is exited
```

[Try it online here](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=r%7Bel_%22aeiou%22--%2CSr%7Dh&input=psst%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20)

Answer (score 6):

## R, <s>44</s> 43 bytes

```r
cat(nchar(gsub("[^aeiou]","",scan(,""),T)))
```

Ungolfed + explanation:

```r
# Read a string from STDIN. scan() automatically constructs a vector
# from input that contains spaces. The what= argument specifies that
# a string will be read rather than a numeric value. Since it's the
# second specified argument to scan(), we can simply do scan(,"").

s <- scan(what = "")

# For each word of the input, remove all consonants using gsub(),
# which is vectorized over its input argument.

g <- gsub("[^aeiou]", "", s, ignore.case = TRUE)

# Print the number of remaining characters in each word to STDOUT
# using cat(), which automatically separates vector values with a
# single space.

cat(nchar(g))
```

Answer (score 5):

## Perl,  <strike>35</strike> <strike>34</strike> 31

```
say map{lc=~y/aeiou//.$"}split
```

`30` characters `+1` for `-n`.

Like a lot of Perl code, this works from right to left.
`split` will split the inputted line on whitespace.
`map` will run the code between `{}` on each word that was split.
`lc` makes the word lower case.
`=~y/aeiou//` will give us the count of vowels.
`.$"` will append a space to the word.
`say` then prints all the words!

Run with:

```
echo 'aeiou AEIOU' | perl -nE'say map{lc=~y/aeiou//.$"}split'
```

Answer (score 5):

## Python 3, 65 bytes

```py
print(*[sum(c in'aeiouAEIOU'for c in w)for w in input().split()])
```

Very straightforward, fairly readable. `w` stands for word, `c` stands for character.

Comment: -4: `lambda s:[sum(c in'aeiouAEIOU'for c in w)for w in s.split()])`

Comment: Correction: -1 by using mine but doing `split(' ')`, since the way you have zero-length words aren't counted

Comment: [64 bytes](https://tio.run/##DcWxCoAgEIDhV7ktjWjpCRoamlpqigYRw4PSwzuRnt6Ej/@nT3wMU62UMIjqT86veg2pMtqYgwydcRjzvKzb0Wl9xwQFMDSURemR6cH2S9e6e2RoxDu4MbGAuBZr2P0)

Answer (score 4):

## Ruby, 38 bytes

```
$><<$*.map{|x|x.count'AIUEOaiueo'}*' '
```

Usage:

```
mad_gaksha@madlab /tmp/ $ ruby t.rb This is the first test case
1 1 1 1 1 2
```

Comment: As of Ruby 2.7, `|x|x` can be replaced with numbered parameter `_1`

Answer (score 4):

## Perl: 30 characters

(Kind of forces the rules: the numbers in the output are separated with as many spaces as the input words were.)

```perl
s|\w+|@{[$&=~/[aeiou]/gi]}|ge
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.3$ while read s; do printf '%-30s --> ' "$s"; perl -pe 's|\w+|@{[$&=~/[aeiou]/gi]}|ge' <<< "$s"; done < test-case.txt
This is the first test case    --> 1 1 1 1 1 2
one plus two equals three      --> 2 1 1 3 2
aeiou AEIOU                    --> 5 5
psst                           --> 0
```

#### Perl: 27 characters

(Just to show how short would be if I didn't forget about `y///`'s return value. Again. Now go and upvote [chilemagic](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/29438/chilemagic)'s [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/50573) which reminded me about `y///`'s return value. Again.)

```perl
s|\w+|lc($&)=~y/aeiou//|ge
```

Comment: Dang this beats my answer. This `s!\w+!lc($&)=~y/aeiou//!ge` gets it down to `27` bytes (26 characters +1 for the `-p`.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I can't count on my fingers anymore how many times I forgot `y///`. :(

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (*ES6*), 68

I/O via popup. Run the snippet in Firefox to test.

```js
// As requested by OP

alert(prompt().replace(/\w+/g,w=>w.replace(/[^aeiou]/ig,'').length))

// Testable
f=s=>s.replace(/\w+/g,w=>w.replace(/[^aeiou]/ig,'').length)

test=[
 ['This is the first test case','1 1 1 1 1 2']
,['one plus two equals three','2 1 1 3 2']
,['aeiou AEIOU', '5 5']
]  

out=x=>O.innerHTML+=x+'\n'

test.forEach(t=>{
  r=f(t[0])
  out('Test '+ ['Fail','OK'][0|r==t[1]]
      +'\nInput:  '+ t[0]
      +'\nOutput: '+r
      +'\nCheck:  '+t[1]+'\n')
})
```

```html
<pre id=O></pre>
```

Answer (score 3):

## Rebol - 70

```
print map-each n split input" "[c: 0 find-all n charset"aeiou"[++ c]c]
```

Answer (score 3):

## Julia, <s>76</s> <s>72</s> <s>69</s> 65 bytes

```rb
for w=split(readline()) print(count(i->i∈"aeiouAEIOU",w)," ")end
```

Ungolfed + explanation:

```rb
# Read a string from STDIN and split it into words
s = split(readline())

# For each word in the string...
for w in s
    # Get the number of vowels of any case in the word
    c = count(i -> i ∈ "aeiouAEIOU", w)

    # Print the number of vowels identified
    print(c, " ")
end
```

This will include a single trailing space, which I'm told is legit.

Answer (score 3):

### PowerShell, 35 bytes

```
%{($_-replace"[^aeiou]",'').length}
```

Kinda boring, but actually competing for once? (PowerShell is case insentitive by default, woo)

Comment: FYI, you needto call this like `echo <word> | code`, where <word> is your word or phrase

Answer (score 3):

## Bash - 85

```
while read l;do for w in $l;do x=${w//[^aouieAOUIE]};echo -n ${#x}\ ;done;echo;done
```

### Explanation

- `read l` read one line from input
- `for w in l` splits the line into words using whitespace separator
- `x=${w//[^aouieAOUIE]/}` deletes all except vowels from the word
- `${#x}` is the length of resulting string === number of vowels

Comment: Feels somehow overdone. The requirement says the input will contain only letters and spaces. So why you prepared it to process multiple input lines? Without `while`..`do`..`done` would be shorter. Also not needed the last `/` in the pattern substitution. And a single literal space is shorter escaped than quoted. `read l;for w in $l;do x=${w//[^aouieAOUIE]};echo -n ${#x}\ ;done;echo`

Comment: I agree but the rule says 'You can write a full program, or a function that takes input from the stdin and outputs the result.' So I've decided to make the full program. I will edit the solution to save two bytes)) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, 95 bytes

Not going to win any contests, but...

```
Print@StringRiffle[ToString[#~StringCount~Characters@"aeiouAEIOU"]&/@StringSplit@InputString[]]
```

Comment: Do you know of any online compilers where I could test this?

Comment: There aren't any, but you can get a free trial [here](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/trial/).

Comment: @CoolGuy You can run Mathematica (Wolfram Language) code online if you get a free account [here](https://programming.wolframcloud.com/app/). (Not sure `InputString` exists in the web interface though, it's a dialog in Mathematica.)

Comment: @Calle In Mathematica scripts, `InputString` takes the next line of input.

Comment: ok, I see. Well still not sure if it will work in the cloud notebook but at least now I know why it's being used for stdin.

Answer (score 2):

## golflua, 55 bytes

```lua
~@W I.r():l():gm("%w+")_,c=W:g("[aeiou]",'')I.w(c,' ')$
```

Basic pattern matching of vowels after forced lowercase. An (ungolfed) Lua equivalent would be

```lua
line=io.read()
for word in line:lower():gmatch("%w+") do
   _,c=word:gsub("[aeiou]",'')
   io.write(c," ")
end
```

Comment: As an aside, for the Lua version, it'd actually be 2 characters shorter to use `gsub('[aeiouAEIOU]','')` and skip out on `lower()`.

Answer (score 2):

### **R**, 139 bytes

Read/write stdout() is terrible

```
s=function(x,y)strsplit(x,y)[[1]]
write(unlist(Map(function(x)sum(x%in%s("AIUEOaiueo","")),Map(s,s(readLines("stdin")," "),"")),),stdout())
```

Comment: [R is not so bad](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/50585/20469). ;) You can use `cat()` rather than `write(..., stdout())`.

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3, 72 bytes

Inspired by [@randomra](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/7311/randomra)'s [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/50574/34736). It's <s>the same length</s>
slightly longer, but using regex instead of list comprehension. It's also less readable.

```py
import re
print(*map(len,re.sub("[^aeiou ]","",input(),0,2).split(" ")))
```

Comment: Save 7 bytes: `import re;print(*map(len,re.sub("[^aeiou ]","",input()).split()))`. (Use newline instead of `;` if you want.)

Comment: @mbomb007 It needs to be case insensitive (`2` is the case insensitive flag) and split by `" "` so there can be 0 length stuff

Comment: Ah, my tests weren't extensive enough to notice that.

Answer (score 2):

## PHP - 94

```py
foreach(explode(' ',$argv[1]) as$d){preg_match_all('/[aeiou]/i',$d,$v);echo count($v[0]).' ';}
```

Ungolfed version

```py
$a = explode(' ',$argv[1]);
foreach($a as $d) {
    preg_match_all('/[aeiou]/i', $d, $v);
    echo count($v[0]).' ';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## Objective-C, 223 bytes

```objective-c
-(void)p:(NSString*)s{NSArray*a=[s componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];for(NSString*w in a){int c=0;for(int i=0;i<w.length;i++){if([@"aeiouAEIOU"containsString:[w substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i,1)]]){c++;}}NSLog(@"%d",c);}}
```

Not the most compact language, but it works.

Uncompressed version:

```objective-c
- (void)p:(NSString*)s{
    NSArray*a=[s componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
    for (NSString*w in a) {
        int c=0;
        for (int i=0;i<w.length;i++) {
            if ([@"aeiouAEIOU" containsString:
                 [w substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i, 1)]]) {
                c++;
            }
        }
        NSLog(@"%d",c);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## Matlab, 73 bytes

Your challenge is not very clear (but it is interesting). I'm assuming

- By "vowel" you mean `a`, `e`, `i`, `o`, `u`.
- The string does not contain leading or trailing spaces

Code:

```
diff(find(regexprep([' ' input('','s') ' '],'[^aeiouAEIOU ]','')==' '))-1
```

Answer (score 2):

## Haskell, <s>76</s> 68 bytes

```
f=interact$unwords.map(show.length).filter(`elem`"aeiouAEIOU").words
```

Straightforward implementation, not sure if there is anything to golf here.

Answer (score 2):

## Perl, <s>60</s> 45

```
$/=" ";while(<>){$n=()=/[aeiou]/gi;print"$n "
```

Thanks to kirbyfan64sos for saving me 15 bytes - that really helped!
Note there's an extra space at the end of the output.

Comment: You can remove the call to `split` by setting adding `$/=" ";`, and you can shorted the loop prefix to `while(<>)`. With those two changes, the code becomes `$/=" ";while(<>){$n=()=/[aeiou]/gi;print"$n "}`, saving 14 bytes!

Answer (score 2):

## [rs](https://github.com/kirbyfan64/rs), 50 bytes

This doesn't quite count; rs was uploaded around 2 weeks after this was posted. However, evidently this wouldn't win anything anyway, so it's still cool.

```
*[aeiou]/_
(^| )[^_\s]+ |$/ 0
[^_\s0]/
(_+)/(^^\1)
```

[Live demo.](http://kirbyfan64.github.io/rs/index.html?script=*%5Baeiou%5D%2F_%0A(%5E%7C%20)%5B%5E_%5Cs%5D%2B%20%7C%24%2F%200%0A%5B%5E_%5Cs0%5D%2F%0A(_%2B)%2F(%5E%5E%5C1)&input=This%20is%20the%20first%20test%20case%0Aone%20plus%20two%20equals%20three%0Aaeiou%20AEIOU%0Apsst)

The implementation is rather straightforward:

```
*[aeiou]/_            Replace all vowels with underscores.
(^| )[^_\s]+ |$/ 0    Replace words that have no vowels with a zero.
[^_\s0]/              Remove all other letters.
(_+)/(^^\1)           Convert the underscore sequences into numbers (e.g. '___' to 3).
```

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), 2̶9̶ 28 bytes

```apl
{+/¨(∊∘'aeiou'⊢)¨' '(≠⊆⊢)⌊⍵}
 +/¨ ⍝ sum each word's vowel bit array
    (∊∘'aeiou'⊢)¨ ⍝ for each word, check for vowels
       ' '(≠⊆⊢) ⍝ split string on spaces
          ⌊⍵ ⍝ convert to lowercase
```

-1 thanks to Razetime

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JU1LDgFBFNw7xds1EXEGEhIrGw7Q9BuGNm/0hxliOxkTEktLsXIBF3CUvgg9Lam8VKWqXvFUdkTOJS06mBlMBIrvN3LF7djufl5NV1auvDOOMVnmqmfr82LAmu78cFVRa3ep3PV98h1gQyLoc8Uank@WsQYPs0SIYqUNGPRnzjUGnxKEVFof2BPg1nJZZxX@3bAHvcFoPA061doEUr/b2ni@hpmifQIRZbCymxQF0A5VmJP8kIOgBfsB)

Comment: `(≠∘' '⊆⊢)` →  `' '(≠⊆⊢)`.

Comment: different idea(26): `{≢¨∩∘'aeiou'¨' '(≠⊆⊢)⌊⍵}`

Comment: @Razetime Oh, that's good, I like the union.

Comment: @Razetime Yeah, my trains are always kind of clunky. I'm still just trying to get the hang of it.

Comment: ≢⍤∩∘'aeiou'¨≠⊆⌊

Comment: @Razetime I meant intersection, don't know why I said union.

Comment: @rak1507 I'm going to have to think about that one for a while  Everytime I start to think I'm getting the hang of APL, one of you 1337 golfers reminds me how much I have to learn. #Humbled

Comment: It's mostly dyalog extended specific stuff, the fact that monadic ≠ in dyalog extended corresponds to ' '∘≠ in regular means partitioning into words is just ≠⊆⌊

Comment: @rak1507 Oh, wow. I really need to look into the differences between the APL variants.

Comment: https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended reading the descriptions of stuff here is quite helpful, there are lots of useful features that you might as well make full use of if you're golfing in extended

Answer (score 1):

## KDB(Q), 30 bytes

```
{sum@'lower[" "vs x]in"aeiou"}
```

## Explanation

```
            " "vs x              / split x string by space
      lower[       ]             / lower case
                    in"aeiou"    / check vowel
 sum@'                           / sum each booleans
{                            }   / lambda
```

## Test

```
q){sum@'lower[" "vs x]in"aeiou"}"This is the first test case"
1 1 1 1 1 2i
```

Answer (score 1):

## Smalltalk - 66 <strike>72</strike>

This is in Smalltalk/X; the names for stdin and stdout may be different in squeak/pharo.

```
Stdin nextLine subStrings do:[:w|(w count:[:c|c isVowel])print.' 'print]
```

In Smalltalk/X (and many other dialects), symbols understand #value:, so it can be abbreviated to 66 chars:

```
 Stdin nextLine subStrings do:[:w|(w count:#isVowel)print.' 'print]
```

If coded as a function which get the string as argument "s":

```
[:s|s subStrings do:[:w|(w count:#isVowel)print.' 'print]]
```

Of course, in real code, one would use a utility function "f", which returns a vector of the counts, and print that. However, the output format is then not exactly what the challenge asked for:

```
f := [:s|s subStrings collect:[:w|(w count:#isVowel)]].
(f value: Stdin nextLine) print.
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2, 76 bytes

I made this before I saw any other solution, then checked to find two P3 solutions that are shorter :( Darn P2 limitations.

```
print' '.join(`sum(y in'aeiouAEIOU'for y in x)`for x in raw_input().split())
```

Answer (score 1):

## SAS, 72

```
data;infile stdin;file stdout;input c$@@;x=countc(c,'aeiou','i');put x@;
```

The restrictive I/O format for this one really hurts this one as it is responsible for 25 of the bytes here.

Answer (score 1):

### PowerShell, 65 bytes

```
($input-split'\s'|%{($_-split''-match'a|e|i|o|u').count})-join' '
```

test by using the pattern below after saving as `vowels.ps1`

```
"the quick brown fox" | vowels.ps1
```

This way it is an actual script and not just a code snippet thereby satisfying constraint:

*"Input must be consumed from the stdin or command line arguments."*

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 bytes

```
Ḳf€ØcL€
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HU07DsIwFLuKlZlLMCCEhMQCBwjtC00JfW0@LWVk4QocgomJvSeBi4SkkmXLsmXXZMwY4/fzVr/7a3oW2yRxeiRexyj2lXZI8BVBaes8PCUqpCOxgOCG0JqQ8oFBXZAmVy3NoSTNAcvVZnfItnXOZ81TXdDFGUfLQwPFV9Th0lIJ7snOV0beRpR8En8)

Found with help from [Mr. Xcoder](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/59487/mr-xcoder) in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57815/jelly-hypertraining)

### Explanation

```
Ḳf€ØcL€ - Main link. Argument: s (a string)  e.g. "aeiou AEIOU"
Ḳ       - Split the input on spaces               ["aeiou", "AEIOU"]
   Øc   - Generate the string "AEIOUaeiou" 
 f€     - Filter out consonants from €ach         ["aeiou", "AEIOU"]
     L€ - Length of €ach                          [5, 5]
```

If the output *must* be space-separated, then append a `K` to the end

Answer (score 1):

## [Arn `-a`](https://github.com/ZippyMagician/Arn), 22 bytes

```
(Ø-═É┤<LO¼‚R€Ê■ÊÕ'à¦┴%
```

My first Arn answer.

`-a` encloses the final array, separating the strings by spaces.

**Uncompressed:** `:s@+{"AEIOUaeiou":i&!!1+}\`

Arn has some trouble with strings, so this is a bit long.

you can omit the `-u` flag to give input directly through STDIN.

-13 bytes from Zippymagician.

[image]

Comment: :s@+{"AEIOUaeiou":i>=0}\ is 2 bytes shorter.

Answer (score 1):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), 42 bytes

```
BEGIN{RS=ORS=FS}$0=gsub(/[aeiouAEIOU]/,e)e
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v/fydXd0686KNjWH4jdgmtVDGzTi0uTNPSjE1Mz80sdXT39Q2P1dVI1U///z89LVSjIKS1WKCnPV0gtLE3MATIzilJTFSIioxTS8kuLAA)

Regards each word as a different record (i.e., line), and substitute them for the count of vowels, calculated by the substitution function `gsub`. `e` is a dummy null variable, that, when appended to the number, makes awk parse it as string, so zero can be printed.

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 6 bytes

```
⌈ƛk∨↔L
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%E2%8C%88%C6%9Bk%E2%88%A8%E2%86%94L&inputs=One%20plus%20two%20equals%20three&header=&footer=)

Explanation:

```
        # Implicit input
⌈       # Split input on ' '
 ƛ      # For each word in input:
  k∨↔   #   Remove all non-vowels
     L  #   Length of resulting string
        # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 4 bytes

```
⌈ƛA∑
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLijIjGm0HiiJEiLCIiLCJUaGlzIGlzIHRoZSBmaXJzdCB0ZXN0IGNhc2UiXQ==)

```
⌈    # Split on spaces
 ƛ   # Map...
  A  # Vowel mask (1 for vowel, 0 for not)
   ∑ # Sum
```

Answer (score 0):

## C# 186

```
public class a{public static void Main(string[] a){Console.Write(string.Join(" ",Console.ReadLine().Split(' ').Select(x=>x.ToCharArray().Count(y=>"aeoui".ToCharArray().Contains(y)))));}}
```

Comment: This fails for the third test case. Your program doesn't seem to count `AEIOU`.

Answer (score 0):

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), 22 bytes

**Solution:**

```
(+/,/"aeiou"=\:)'" "\_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/X0NbX0dfKTE1M79UyTbGSlNdSUEpJl7JPy9VISCntFghpDxfwbWwNDEHyMwoSk1V@v8fAA)

**Examples:**

```
> (+/,/"aeiou"=\:)'" "\_"This is the first test case"
1 1 1 1 1 2
> (+/,/"aeiou"=\:)'" "\_"aeiou AEIOU"
5 5
```

**Explanation:**

Interpretted right-to-left, lowercase input, split on whitespace, then check each word against each vowel, flatten and sum results:

```
(+/,/"aeiou"=\:)'" "\_ / the solution
                     _ / convert to lowercase
                 " "\  / split on " "
                '      / each
(              )       / do all this together
     "aeiou"=\:        / check each-left (\:) "aeiou" equal (=) to right argument
   ,/                  / flatten
 +/                    / sum
```

Answer (score 0):

## Java 8, <s>137</s> 135 bytes

**As full program:**

```java
interface M{static void main(String[]a){for(String s:a[0].split(" "))System.out.print(s.replaceAll("[^aeiouAEIOU]","").length()+" ");}}
```

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##LYy7jsIwEEV/ZeTK1rIWNVtRbEGxokBUUZBmk0lwcDzGnoSX@HYvSFtenXPugDN@cqQwtKdSXBBKHTYEP48sKK6BmV0LI7qgd5Jc6KsazaPj9D8hr7Ba1jZH70QrUMbsbllotDyJjS9FdLaJon@9rr3XqjogOZ7W35vtvlYLpYz1FHo5avPx7r@ez1KKHAnOk2tO8Jv4EqDjKwzTGKkFninBm3u836Dl/g8)

**As function:**

A full program is apparently shorter than a function in this case (**137 bytes**):

```java
v->{for(String s:new java.util.Scanner(System.in).nextLine().split(" "))System.out.print(s.replaceAll("[^aeiouAEIOU]","").length()+" ");}
```

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##LY9LTsMwEIb3nGLklS2oD0AEUhcskKAsKthURXKdSerUGRs/0paqZw8OjTSj0by/v1ODWjiP1NWHUVsVI7wrQ5c7AEMJQ6M0wmpKAQZnatD8awqDqErtWrxYTCoZDSsgeIJxWDxfGhf4OgVDLcRHwiN05Y/MyVi51ooIS/scE/bSkJCEp/RmCLmQ0VuTOAMmxDzgcpK@XEo8yoDeFqCltZxtvhUal5cvrx@fW/bAmJAWqU17Lu6n/eo6Vjc8n3e24M2U/yr6onEG3GxBiZtAkppTtnbWdh3THuEnG32AXXBHgsadoMu9xxrcgAGmvlW/Z6hd@wc)

**Explanation:**

```java
interface M{                       // Class
  static void main(String[]a){     //  Mandatory main-method
    for(String s:a[0].split(" "))  //   Loop over the words of the input:
      System.out.print(s.replaceAll("[^aeiouAEIOU]","")
                                   //    Remove every non-vowel,
                        .length()  //    and print the length of the remainder
                       +" ");      //    + a space
                                   //   End of loop (implicit / single-line body)
  }                                //  End of main-method
}                                  // End of class
```

Answer (score 0):

### [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 23 bytes

**19 bytes code + 4 for `-p040`.**

```perl
$_=lc=~y/aeiou//.$"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3jYn2bauUj8xNTO/VF9fT0Xp/38wW8HR1dM/9F9@QUlmfl7xf90CAxMDAA)

Answer (score 0):

## Common Lisp, 74 bytes

```
(loop as i =(read)do(print(count-if(lambda(x)(find x"AEIOU"))(string i))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Fco7GsIgEEXhrdwv1VC4BAsLCysrF0B4xFHCII@Ibh7jaf9jApc0BgWRBF3AOFJ22iorlDLHSkZarAf2FPQ6W01dkedo0afT@XK9TUpRqfu5gNXeGPXu8GpsnpizvCO8dDzampyFbC7j70F/P7Cy/AA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) v2.0a0, 5 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
mè\vS
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=2.0a0&code=behcdlM&input=InRoZSBxdWljayBicm93biBmb3gganVtcGVkIG92ZXIgdGhlIGxhenkgZG9nIg)

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 106 bytes

```python
for x in input().upper().split():
 p=0
 for y in x:
  if 1065233>>(ord(y)-65)&1:
   p+=1
 print(p,end=" ")
```

Ehh, fairly long solution, but it's a start

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FUzdDoIgGL33Kc68aLB@pjlda9N3qcCkFL4ISnp5gu1sZ@eXgpuMbk5kYxyNxQqlE8g7xg@eSNrEb5pV0ucC1FcFci/k3pocqBF11bXHphkGZqxgge@7lm/qHIK2fZ1mVmnHaCe16EuUPEY3Sby8uj1xtear0@eKh19ICpiPtMj5fPkFCHP/Aw)

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
O€ṃʂ
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPU8lRTIlODIlQUMlRTElQjklODMlQ0ElODImZm9vdGVyPSZpbnB1dD10aGUlMjBxdWljayUyMGJyb3duJTIwZm94JTIwanVtcGVkJTIwb3ZlciUyMHRoZSUyMGxhenklMjBkb2cmZmxhZ3M9JUUxJUI5JUEw)

Add the `Ṡ` flag if the input needs to be joined on spaces.

##### Explanation

```python
O€ṃʂ  # Implicit input
O     # Split it on spaces
 €ṃ   # Then check if each is a vowel
   ʂ  # Sum each inner list
      # Implicit output
```